# how to show a jQuery animation effect before page is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample page which has demo `Lorem ipsum` content. There is a button called "SHOW PAGE LOADER". When I click on it. Its showing a page loading effect. Here is the live link : http://creativeartbd.com/demo/page-load/index.html

Now I want to show this page loading effect before page content is fully loaded. is it possible ? If so, How can I do this ?

I used this code to click the button after page is load but it's not working :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pageload-link').click();
});
```

Here is the full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pagewrap" class="pagewrap">        
        <div class="show" id="page-1">
            <!-- Top Navigation -->         
            <section class="columns clearfix">
                <div class="column">                        
                    <p><a class="pageload-link">Show Page Loader</a></p>
                </div>
            </section>              
        </div><!-- /container -->

        <!-- The new page dummy; this would be dynamically loaded content -->
        <div class="container" id="page-2">             
            <section>
                <h2>This is an example for a new page.</h2>
                <p><a class="pageload-link" href="#page-1">Go back</a></p>
            </section>
        </div><!-- /container -->

        <div id="loader" class="pageload-overlay" data-opening="M20,15 50,30 50,30 30,30 Z;M0,0 80,0 50,30 20,45 Z;M0,0 80,0 60,45 0,60 Z;M0,0 80,0 80,60 0,60 Z" data-closing="M0,0 80,0 60,45 0,60 Z;M0,0 80,0 50,30 20,45 Z;M20,15 50,30 50,30 30,30 Z;M30,30 50,30 50,30 30,30 Z">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M30,30 50,30 50,30 30,30 Z"/>
            </svg>           

        </div><!-- /pageload-overlay -->


     <p style="margin:0 150px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque rerum ipsum sint consectetur quos vitae veritatis magnam ipsa quas maiores natus quibusdam inventore reiciendis, alias quae eaque! Quod, voluptates, iste.</p><br/>

     <p style="margin:0 150px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque rerum ipsum sint consectetur quos vitae veritatis magnam ipsa quas maiores natus quibusdam inventore reiciendis, alias quae eaque! Quod, voluptates, iste.</p><br/>

     <p style="margin:0 150px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque rerum ipsum sint consectetur quos vitae veritatis magnam ipsa quas maiores natus quibusdam inventore reiciendis, alias quae eaque! Quod, voluptates, iste.</p><br/>          


    </div><!-- /pagewrap -->
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/svgLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var pageWrap = document.getElementById( 'pagewrap' ),
                pages = [].slice.call( pageWrap.querySelectorAll( 'div.container' ) ),
                currentPage = 0,
                triggerLoading = [].slice.call( pageWrap.querySelectorAll( 'a.pageload-link' ) ),
                loader = new SVGLoader( document.getElementById( 'loader' ), { speedIn : 100 } );

            function init() {
                triggerLoading.forEach( function( trigger ) {
                    trigger.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                        ev.preventDefault();
                        loader.show();
                        // after some time hide loader
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            loader.hide();

                            classie.removeClass( pages[ currentPage ], 'show' );
                            // update..
                            currentPage = currentPage ? 0 : 1;
                            classie.addClass( pages[ currentPage ], 'show' );

                        }, 2000 );
                    } );
                } );    
            }

            init();
        })();


       $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.pageload-link').click();
       }); 

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to trigger a click on it after the page has fully loaded. Is this to hide it? I suggest implementing your loaded in the following way:

Create all the page markup, however make sure that your loading overlay is above everything, for instance, by using z-index.

```
<div class="actual-page"></div>

<div class="load-overlay"></div>
```

Make sure all the "shown" styles are applied to your loader. By default it should be visible, since that's how you want to start the page.

```
.load-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then you can place any animations or gif to display that loading is happening, and inside your onready handler you should hide the loader, since that's when the page has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.load-overlay').hide();
});
```

Comment: Yeah. I can see you're using SVGs for the actual animation, but the answer doesn't change much. It's just that instead of hiding the element you'll edit it. This however always happens in `$(document).ready()`. You simply need to edit it so that the "unwrapped" svg is shown by default.

Comment: Hi I can't implement it yet :(